# Similar bootstrap alerts in Material Angualr

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am working with material angular, but I dont Find nothing similar an alerts of bootstrap, what can do?

```
<label [ngClass]="{'alert-danger':process.status === 1,
                        'alert-warning':process.status === 2,
                        'alert-success': process.status === 3 }"
         class="list-process alert">
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) can help.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use a `MatSnackBar`. https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview
For different looks you can define classes in your global styles and then always open your snack bar with the look you want.

Comment: The author was referring to this : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#alerts so it doesn't answer the question (but thanks for the reference)

Comment: @Thomas You can achieve the same with theming and restyling of the MatSnackbar

Answer (score 3):

I've found (but not tried yet) this, it's based on Angular Material and Bootstrap 4.x

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples

It has the same alerts as regular bootstrap (ie: a div that you can insert anywhere, and not a toaster like alert (which are nice too, but not the same usage)

[image: alerts]